# Set the selected option by attribute name (select tag)

Tags: jquery, html, select

I'm doing some javascript/jquery for my application and i need some help.

I have a select with many options. I want to select the option with the attribute name='myName'.

I know setting it by value is pretty trivial.

```
$("#my-select").val(myVal);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why does an option have a `name`?

Comment: `<option>` elements can't have `name` attributes in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#my-select option[name='myName']").prop('selected', true);
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/349e1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("option[name='myName']").prop('selected',true);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Za38H/)**

However as stated in the comments, the name attribute for option elements is obsolete.

Comment: I'm appending options with jquery. In some point i have two options with the same value, but their texts are diferents. I cant change the value because the value is the id of the option (entity), and ill use it to update my database. So when i need to add a new option with a existent value, i just add an name to the option. I dont know if this is the best way, but seems to work.